# Printing empty boxes?

Tags: java, arrays, string, loops, for-loop

The following code is supposed to convert each value in an array containing integers to a char which is then added to a string variable.

```
 else if (response.equalsIgnoreCase("toString"))
        {
            strContents = "";
            for(int i = 0; i<values.length; i++)
            {
                strContents = strContents + (char)values[i];
            }
            System.out.print("\nString text (from array values): " + strContents);
        }
```

However the output I get is this:
[image]

'values' is the name of the array.

Comment: what does the "values" contain ?

Comment: An array of integers.

Comment: remove the (char) casting!

Comment: Your code is fine as it is **if** you want to print the chars by their ASCII codes which are stored inside `values`. **But** these ASCII codes do not correspond to printable chars so you see these squares.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use：

```
strContents = strContents + values[i];
```

You do not need cast a `int` to a `char`.